# Hatching the definition area of the matplotlib function

Tags: python

I want to make a hatching of the function definition area, something similar as in the example

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
        plt.title('$f(x)= x^3 + x^2 + 17 $')
        plt.minorticks_on()
        plt.grid()
        plt.xlabel('x')
        plt.ylabel('y')
             
        x = np.linspace(-100, 100)
        y = lambda x:  x**3 + x**2 + 17
        ax.plot(x, y(x))
        ax.axhline(color='green', lw=2, alpha=0.7)
        
        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, self)
        canvas.draw()
        canvas.get_tk_widget().place(x=300, y=0)
```

[image: function]
[image: example]

I tried filling in the area below the line but it filled in the entire area

Answer (score 1):

[Hatches](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/shapes_and_collections/hatch_style_reference.html) in combination with [fill_between](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.fill_between.html) should to the trick:

[image]

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

#your code
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.title('$f(x)= x^3 + x^2 + 17 $')
plt.minorticks_on()
plt.grid()
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')

x = np.linspace(-100, 100)
y = lambda x: x ** 3 + x ** 2 + 17
ax.axhline(color='green', lw=2, alpha=0.7)
#end of your code

# use two regions to create two hatches, one for y>0, one for y<0
# zorder = 2 to keep the hatches in front of the gridline
# change the amount of '|' to change the hatch density
for mask, color in zip([y(x) > 0, y(x) < 0], ["red", "green"]):
    ax.fill_between(x[mask], y(x[mask]), y2=0, hatch='|||', zorder=2,
                    color="none", edgecolor=color, linewidth=0.0)
ax.plot(x, y(x))
plt.show()
```